# Mongodb counting combination of items in array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I have something like:
`

```
[
{
    ....
    tags : ["A","B"]
},
{
    ....
    tags : ["A","B"]
},
{
    ....
    tags : ["J","K"]
},
{
    ....
    tags : ["A","B","C"]
}
]`
```

With the Aggregation Framwork I'd like to group by array combinations to have something like this:

```
[
{
    _id:["A","B"],
    count : 3
},
{
    _id:["J","K"],
    count : 1
},
{
    _id:["A","C"],
    count : 1

   },
{
        _id:["B","C"],
        count : 1
    },
]
```

is it possible? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query

- for each tag of size 1, makes it `["V"] -> ["V" null]`
  (if you dont want to count the pairs with the null you can filter out in the final results)
- map and for each member we say its together with the rest members
  For example `["A" "B" "C"]` will make  "A" together with `["B" "C"]`,
  "B" together with `["A" "C"]` etc (we count double, we will divide next with 2)
- unwind that arrays
- group by pairs, but shorted pairs `["A" "B"] = ["B" "A"]`
- take the count 0.5 (instead of 1) (its like we divide with 2)

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/w3mjLZidrFW)

```js
aggregate(
[ {
  "$set" : {
    "tags" : {
      "$cond" : [ {
        "$eq" : [ {
          "$size" : "$tags"
        }, 1 ]
      }, {
        "$concatArrays" : [ "$tags", [ null ] ]
      }, "$tags" ]
    }
  }
}, {
  "$set" : {
    "a" : {
      "$map" : {
        "input" : "$tags",
        "in" : {
          "member" : "$$t",
          "togetherWith" : {
            "$setDifference" : [ "$tags", [ "$$t" ] ]
          }
        },
        "as" : "t"
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  "$unwind" : {
    "path" : "$a"
  }
}, {
  "$replaceRoot" : {
    "newRoot" : "$a"
  }
}, {
  "$unwind" : {
    "path" : "$togetherWith"
  }
}, {
  "$group" : {
    "_id" : {
      "$cond" : [ {
        "$lt" : [ "$member", "$togetherWith" ]
      }, [ "$member", "$togetherWith" ], [ "$togetherWith", "$member" ] ]
    },
    "count" : {
      "$sum" : 0.5
    }
  }
}, {
  "$set" : {
    "count" : {
      "$toInt" : "$count"
    }
  }
} ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to break array elements into separate documents.

Then you can sum over each to get the result.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{  $unwind : "$newTags"  },
{  $group:
  { "_id" : "$newTags",
   "count":{$sum:1}
  }
}])
```